# looping through array to find token and translate the token in C

Tags: arrays, loops, token

I am creating a function to loop through a dictionary array searching for an instance of a word and returning the translation of the supplied word which is located in the odd indices of the array.  my output continues to be "ur is (null)" when it should be "ur is you are" based on the dictionary file.

```
char *
translate(char **array, int count, char *token)
{
int i = 0;
while (i < count)
    {
    if (array[i] == token) //string compare
       {

       // i +=2;
       // printf("%s\n",array[i]);
       return array[i + 1];
       i +=2;
       printf("%s\n",array[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
return array[i + 1];
}
```

Comment: You should probably say what language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct way to compare strings in C.  The `==` operator is comparing **pointers**.  Instead, you need to use a **string comparison operator** like `strcmp()` or `strncmp()`.

You should also carefully consider how the program will reach each of your return statements, and what the value of `i` will be in each instance.  Testing with `printf()` like you're doing is a good idea - do more of it!